# How to insert userform data in new row below headers?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, excel-tables

I have a userform with a Submit button to insert data into the top row of a table, below the headers, in a worksheet called "database2".

The issue is adding the top row. I tried recording a macro to see the code.

The button is supposed to:

- add a new row at the top of the table in worksheet "database2", keeping the same formulas and formatting as the row that was previously there (I think since it's a table, it will do the formatting and formulas automatically)
- Copy the data from the userform to the table
- Clear the userform
- Refresh data in a listbox
- Save the workbook
- Prompt a message

MSO 2021

```vb
Private Sub btnsubmit_Click()

range("A2").Select
Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add (1)

range("A2").Value = Now
range("B2").Value = Me.cmbor
range("C2").Value = Me.cmbun
range("D2").Value = Me.cmbna
range("E2").Value = Me.cmbad
range("F2").Value = Me.cmbci
range("G2").Value = Me.cmbprod
range("H2").Value = Me.cmbm
range("I2").Value = Me.cmbh
range("J2").Value = Me.cmb2
range("K2").Value = Me.cmbj
range("L2").Value = Me.cmbx
range("M2").Value = Me.cmbsc
range("X2").Value = Me.cmbtr

Me.cmbor.Value = ""
Me.cmbun.Value = ""
Me.cmbna.Value = ""
Me.cmbad.Value = ""
Me.cmbci.Value = ""
Me.cmbprod.Value = ""
Me.cmbm.Value = ""
Me.cmbh.Value = ""
Me.cmb2.Value = ""
Me.cmbj.Value = ""
Me.cmbx.Value = ""
Me.cmbsc.Value = ""
Me.cmbtr.Value = ""

Call Refresh_Data

ThisWorkbook.Save

MsgBox "Uploaded"

End Sub
```

I tried multiple tutorials. Macros, addrows, shift xl1up copyformat from right or below".

Comment: [THIS](https://youtu.be/RVLwhVr22y8) will get you started. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Rows("2:2").Insert
```